# filtering negative values

Tags: java, android, math

How to filter negative values from a set of arrays? I just want to get the positive values, is there any specific class to do it in Java? Is the Math.max in Java is the correct class to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the Math.max in Java is the correct class to do it?

Math is class and [`Math.max()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#max%28double,%20double%29) is static method ,

You just simply need to check each element against the condition

```
if(number < 0 ){
   //negative
}
```

Comment: Oops, my bad, I mean max() method of Math class xD
I see thanks for the tips! =)

Answer (score 5):

**Java 8+**

You can use `Stream` and lambda expressions:

```
Integer[] numbers = {1, -5, 3, 2, -4, 7, 8};

Integer[] positives = Arrays.asList(numbers)
                            .stream()
                            .filter(i -> i > 0)        // >= to include 0
                            .toArray(Integer[]::new);

System.out.println(Arrays.asList(positives));
```

Output:

```
[1, 3, 2, 7, 8]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate through the array and check whether the number at specific index is greater than zero or not.

```
int[] A={10,-20,30,44,-9};
for ( int item : A ) {
   if (item > 0)
      //Do whatever you want here.
   else
     //Ignore negative number. 
}
```